# python - Change keyboard language

Tags: python

I am trying to change the keyboard language in python (windows). I have searched everywhere for a way to do it and the most common answer is

```
import win32api
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000409',1) # to switch to english
win32api.LoadKeyboardLayout('00000401',1) # to switch to arabic
```

But the only thing this code does is add another language to the current list of languages on my pc - it doesn't change the language's keyboard (when I try typing something after I ran the script it keeps typing in the same language).
BTW, I am using windows

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Keyboard and language settings are per-process in Windows 7 and earlier. So, you could be successfully setting the language for the Python script, which then ends, leaving no trace.

Comment: I'm using windows 8... Also, my code is longer than just this command and I even added a time.sleep for a minute in order to see the change - but the language still stayed the same..

Answer (score 1):

This is works for me

```
from win32con import WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST
from win32gui import GetForegroundWindow
from win32api import SendMessage

if SendMessage( GetForegroundWindow(), WM_INPUTLANGCHANGEREQUEST, 0, 0x4090409) == 0:
    print('設定英文鍵盤成功！')
```

Answer (score 0):

שלום נגה.

I managed to do it with keyboard events & shortcut assignment.

1. go to windows 7 > control panel > "text services and input language" (or right-click langauge-bar > settings)
2. assign keys for the uni-directional language.  e.g. "To English", and "To Hebrew".  I've chosen Alt-Shift-7 and Alt-Shift-8, because they're rarely used elsewhere.
3. from your app, send the key combination for the appropriate language, when needed.

**Note:**

if "your app" is an external utility (I wrote mine in Python), then it must NOT invoke a window, otherwise /your-app/ will steal the focus, and will get the language change.  in python I solved it by using a GUI-less pyw script filename. (or invoke the script with pythonw.exe)

this article shows how to send keyboard events in python:

https://python-decompiler.com/article/2012-11/how-to-generate-keyboard-events-in-python